# python search in a string with find

Tags: python, wordpress

i'm trying to find a string in the headers of response after login in wordpress script , so i tried with this find method :

```
import urllib, urllib2, os, sys, requests , re
....
....
req = urllib2.Request(url, urllib.urlencode(dict(data)), dict(headers))
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
res = dict(response.headers)
res1 = 'wp-admin'
print res.find(res1);
```

and i get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\wp2\wp12.py", line 29, in <module>
    print res.find(res1);
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'find'
```

so any idea how to search in dict(response.headers) or transform it into text to use find function correctly ? and thanks a lot for any help :)

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?  You're looking for the string `wp-admin` inside of a dictionary and what are you expecting the result to be?

Comment: Are you searching for `wp-admin` in the keys of `reasponse.headers`, the values, or both?

Comment: You've converted the headers into a `dict`, while `find` method is for `str` type.

Comment: i want to see if wp-admin exist in dict(response.headers) to check the login , (and it's there for real but i can't confirm that with find function :) )

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use "find" on dict, but you can find in keys/values. Followed code will find wp-admin in values and return key/value in dict. add k.find if you also want find in keys.

```
dict([(k,v) for k,v in res.iteritems() if v.find('wp-admin') >=0])
```

Comment: but how to verifie that 'wp-admin' is in the dict ?

Comment: @user3925122, a dict contains key and value. { "key1":"value1", "key2":"wp-admin' }. You cannot just check the dict, instead, you want to check key or value. It's up to your logic to check whether key or value has 'wp-admin'. Or if you only want to know whether there's a key called 'wp-admin', you can just check res['wp-admin']

Comment: here is the dict(response.headers): 
`{'x-powered-by': 'PHP/5.3.28', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'set-cookie': 'wordpress_test_cookie=
WP+Cookie+check; path=/blog/, wordpress_38b05fc993d7b123a9db72281bf1c40e=+; expires=Sun, 11-Aug-2013
 15:27:13 GMT; path=/blog/wp-admin,.. }` how to know if it contain wp-admin like print  res['wp-admin'] ??

Comment: @user3925122, in your case, it's contained in value of key 'set-cookie', it's not a name of key. You can use code in my answer to get the result. (dict([(k,v) for k,v in res.iteritems() if v.find('wp-admin') >=0]) )